# Changing the color of navigation drawer group title text

Tags: android, material-components-android, navigationview, material-components, android-navigationview

I want to change the color of `Title1` in the navigation drawer

[image: .]

Answer (score 0):

It is based on the **`android:textColorSecondary`** color.

You can define something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.ItemGroup"
    ..>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.ItemGroup" parent="">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

[image]